# RichEdit control stop drawing text when it became a parent for other control

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, richedit

RichEdit control stop drawing text when it became a parent for other control.

Is this a feature or a bug?
Is it possible to make RichEdit to be a parent for other control?

Check out next app:

-- Form1.dfm ---

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 282
  ClientWidth = 418
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object RichEdit1: TRichEdit
    Left = 16
    Top = 72
    Width = 145
    Height = 105
    Font.Charset = RUSSIAN_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Font.Style = []
    Lines.Strings = (
      'RichEdit1')
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

-- Form1.dfm ---

--- Unit1.pas ---

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Parent := RichEdit1;
  RichEdit1.Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

--- Unit1.pas ---

Test under Delphi XE5 + Win 7.

I want to create RichEdit with Edit button like this

[image]

This is the result that I want to get - RichEdit with DropDown Editor:

[image]

Comment: This is my question. Is it possible to make RichEdit to be a parent for other control?

Comment: Well, the question edit changes the question to that. I suspect that the answer is no.

Comment: Far and away the simplest solution is to put your button on top of the rich edit control with the same parent as the rich edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an interposer class that handles the `WM_PAINT` message like so:

```
type
  TRichEdit = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit)
  protected
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  end;

procedure TRichEdit.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  DefaultHandler(Message);
end;
```

For reasons lost in the mists of time, `TCustomRichEdit` does some special handling of `WM_PAINT` that was only actually needed for the original version of the rich edit DLL. Moreover, this special handling breaks normal painting when another control is parented to the rich edit. As such, fixing the issue requires re-establishing standard VCL/Windows paint handling, which is what the code above does.

That said, I doubt nesting a button inside a rich edit is really what you want - the text won't wrap around it, for example.

Comment: Thank you Chris. It works. How did you know?
Now with EM_SETRECTNP I can reduce the width of text area so the text would wrap before the button.

Comment: @DmitryB - back in the Win98/Win2000 days I wrote my own rich edit v2/3 wrapper and implemented an embedded custom ruler for it. As such, I knew nesting controls to a TRichEdit worked - it was just a matter of digging out the old source...